# Performance issues with SQL with WHERE column = 'x' vs. field = N'x'

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

We have a SQL statement with a simple `WHERE` clause:

```
no_identificador_rubro.cod_identificador_rubro = 'SRISueldos'
```

This column is of `varchar(10)` datatype and it's supposed to be compared with a 'x' value (a non-Unicode) and I'm doing it, however the performance is awful.

But, contrary to what theory dictates, if I do it the 'wrong' way, comparing a `varchar` with a Unicode value (just by adding the `N` prefix), surprisingly, it's MUCH faster, 10 times faster...  totally opposite to what was expected.

```
no_identificador_rubro.cod_identificador_rubro = N'SRISueldos'
```

If I compare the 2 execution plans, they are completely different, but why?

What am I not seeing? What am I missing? What's the reason?

We use SQL Server in Azure with a `modern_spanish_ci_as` collation with 10 DTUs.

```
SELECT 
    no_rol_persona.cod_persona
FROM
    no_rol_cabecera
JOIN 
    no_rol_persona ON no_rol_cabecera.cod_rol_cabecera = no_rol_persona.cod_rol_cabecera
JOIN
    no_rol_rubro ON no_rol_persona.cod_rol_persona = no_rol_rubro.cod_rol_persona
JOIN 
    no_rol_detalle ON no_rol_rubro.cod_rol_rubro = no_rol_detalle.cod_rol_rubro
JOIN 
    no_rubro ON no_rol_rubro.cod_rubro = no_rubro.cod_rubro
JOIN 
    si_sucursal ON no_rol_cabecera.cod_sucursal = si_sucursal.cod_sucursal
JOIN  
    si_empresa ON si_sucursal.cod_empresa = si_empresa.cod_empresa
JOIN
    no_tipo_rol ON no_rol_cabecera.cod_tipo_rol = no_tipo_rol.cod_tipo_rol
JOIN
    no_plantilla_identificador ON no_rubro.cod_plantilla_detalle = no_plantilla_identificador.cod_plantilla_detalle
JOIN 
    no_identificador_rubro ON no_plantilla_identificador.cod_identificador_rubro = no_identificador_rubro.cod_identificador_rubro
WHERE
    si_empresa.cod_empresa = '01' 
    AND no_tipo_rol.cod_tipo_rol IN ('QT005', 'QT003', 'QT001', 'QT002')
    AND no_rol_cabecera.fecha_inicial_rol >= @FechaIni 
    AND no_rol_cabecera.fecha_inicial_rol <= @FechaFin 
    AND no_identificador_rubro.cod_identificador_rubro = 'SRISueldos'  -- <- LOOK HERE
    AND no_rol_detalle.valor_rol_detalle <> 0
GROUP BY 
    no_rol_persona.cod_persona
```

I attach the 2 execution plans.

Slow plan:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkA7APxsa

Fast plan:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1OsCvxoa

Next Round:

trying OPTION(MAXDOP 1)  (4 Minutes)

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1-9WZ7ia

trying OPTION(RECOMPILE) (7 Minutes) (even worse)

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJT1f-7op

trying again N'xxx'  (6 Seconds)  Why ????

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryEEGZXop

Comment: `N` is not Unicode; just "national character set". I stand corrected. It seems that in SQL Server N is implemented as Unicode.

Comment: Your `AND no_tipo_rol.cod_tipo_rol in  (...)` condition has a different last value between your two queries. Do you still see different performance if they are changed to be the same?

Comment: I changed the last value in that 'in' because I didn't want to hit a cache result. Just in case. But answering... yes the difference persist.

Comment: *Not really an answer:* It looks like the slower plan used `cod_identificador_rubro = 'SRISueldos'` as the starting point. In the faster execution plan, that starting point was not used due to the type mismatch, and `si_empresa.cod_empresa = '01'` was used instead. I guess the engine just happened to stumble across a plan that worked better. *Not really a fix:* Sometimes, when SQL server goes overboard with parallel operations and hash joins, I add a `OPTION(MAXDOP 1)` to the end of the query to force a single threaded plan. Not really a fix, but sometimes works.

Comment: Have you tried adding OPTION(RECOMPILE) ?

Comment: What is the collation of the database ?

Comment: the collation is: modern_spanish_ci_as

Comment: Server collation is Azure Sql Server default: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  Which is a SQL Server collation but mine is a Windows Collation... maybe that interferes?

Answer (score 0):

TN pointed me towards the solution

Initially I thought that SQL Server was smart enough to find the best execution plan. but after several tests I have discovered that it does NOT.

I had to reformulate the SQL statement by placing the smallest tables at the beginning and it also helped to rearrange the where conditions in the same order as the tables.

Now I have results in about 5 seconds instead of 4 minutes.

```
SELECT 
    no_rol_persona.cod_persona
FROM
si_empresa 
JOIN si_sucursal ON si_empresa.cod_empresa = si_sucursal.cod_empresa
JOIN no_rol_cabecera ON si_sucursal.cod_sucursal = no_rol_cabecera.cod_sucursal
JOIN no_tipo_rol ON no_rol_cabecera.cod_tipo_rol = no_tipo_rol.cod_tipo_rol
JOIN no_rol_persona ON no_rol_cabecera.cod_rol_cabecera = no_rol_persona.cod_rol_cabecera
JOIN no_rol_rubro ON no_rol_persona.cod_rol_persona = no_rol_rubro.cod_rol_persona
JOIN no_rol_detalle ON no_rol_rubro.cod_rol_rubro = no_rol_detalle.cod_rol_rubro
JOIN no_rubro ON no_rol_rubro.cod_rubro = no_rubro.cod_rubro
JOIN no_plantilla_identificador ON no_rubro.cod_plantilla_detalle = no_plantilla_identificador.cod_plantilla_detalle
JOIN no_identificador_rubro ON no_plantilla_identificador.cod_identificador_rubro = no_identificador_rubro.cod_identificador_rubro
WHERE
    si_empresa.cod_empresa = '01' 
    AND no_rol_cabecera.fecha_inicial_rol >= @FechaIni 
    AND no_rol_cabecera.fecha_inicial_rol <= @FechaFin 
    AND no_tipo_rol.cod_tipo_rol IN ('QT005', 'QT003', 'QT001', 'QT002')
    AND no_identificador_rubro.cod_identificador_rubro = 'SRISueldos'  -- <- LOOK HERE
    AND no_rol_detalle.valor_rol_detalle <> 0
GROUP BY 
    no_rol_persona.cod_persona
```